# jQuery AnythingSlider shows only 8 slides

Tags: jquery, slider, anythingslider

I'm using a great jQuery content plugin called [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/). The problem is that it shows only 8 slides when there are 16 of those in the result of the query. You can see that on the web-site itself http://tehnoluki.ru/. The list of the products below (with smaller images) is being populated with the same query. That list shows 16 products which is correct while AnythingSlider contains only 8 slides. This is pretty weird as I've used this a lot of times and shown a lot more slides in the same slider. However I'm unable to do this now.

Any hints on why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Well i have tried AnythingSlider but finally i switched on Suro Slider [http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/] it has many features more than AnythingSlider, here http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/demos.html] are some demos. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue from the given URL.

Each list item contains two divisions and these divisions are not properly formatted.

I self-tested this by removing all second divisions from the given list items and it worked fine with 16  slides.

I found there are some un-matched

and  tags in each list item.

Please update your code to properly match these.

Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Thanks.